# VSCode Extension: Get outline of function for custom outliner

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, add-on

I'm trying to create a custom outliner for VSCode (currently only for python), but I don't find measures to get the information I needed.

I like to get information in this manner this:

- Array:

  - [0]

    - label: "foo"
    - type: "Function"
    - parameters: [...]
    - Range: [...]
    - innerDefinitions: [0]
  - [1]

    - label: "myclass"
    - type: "Class"
    - base_class: ""
    - Range: [...]
    - innerDefinitions:

      - [0]:

        - [...]
      - [1]:

        - [...]

Currently I try to get outline information via `vscode.commands.executeCommand(     'vscode.XXX'`

#### What I've tried:

Here is what commands I've tried and what result I received.

- `vscode.executeImplementationProvider`

  - half usable: range of functionname. Other information is missing
- `vscode.executeHoverProvider`

  - half usable: string of function head (including `def` keyword)
- `vscode.executeDefinitionProvider`

  - half usable: range of complete function. Individual information must be "parsed out"
- `vscode.executeTypeDefinitionProvider`

  - Never provided any result
- `vscode.executeDeclarationProvider`

  - Never provided any result
- `vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider`

  - Goes in a good direction. However
    (1) Does only work on the whole document (not single function)
    (2) Does only return first-level entities (i.e. class methods are not included in result)

Is there any API call I've overseen?
I wonder how the built-in outliner works, as it  contains all-level information.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to use `vscode.commands.executeCommand<vscode.Location[]>("vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider", uri, position)`
2. This will give you the full outline of one file. There is no way to receive a partial outline.
3. Note: `innerDefinitions` are called `children` here.
4. Regarding the detail of the outline:

- How detailed (and correct) an outline is going to be, *depends on the implementation of the provider*. Also, provider's information is no necessarily consistent among languages. This is very important to keep in mind!

  - At the moment (2021/03), the standard SymbolProvider for...

    - ... Python will have a child for each parameter and local variable of a function. They will not be distinguishable
    - ... C++ will contain no children for parameters. But it will have the parameter types in its `name`. (e.g. `name` of `void foo(string p)` will be `foo(string): void`.
  - As you can see, both act differently with their own quirks.
- You could create and register a DocumentSymbolProvider yourself, that would return a level of detail you need (see [VSCode Providers](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features))

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66486297/6702598