# Language Server Protocol: Get Symbol Information of inner functions/classes

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol, python-language-server

#### What I want

I'm searching for a command in VSCode (a la `vscode.commands.executeCommand(...)`) that returns symbol information (outline) of inner functions/classes of a function/class.

#### Example

A command like
`vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.??', Range(2,6))` on

```
1  def foo1():
2     def innerfoo():
3        print("hello")
4     def innerfoo2():
5        print("world)
6     innerfoo()
```

should return an array with `innerfoo` and `innerfoo2`.

#### What I've found

The command `vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider')` will provide 1st-level symbol information for the whole document.
E.g. in

```
class MyClass:
  def foo(self):
    pass
```

only `MyClass` is found

Comment: where have you found `vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider`

Comment: I made that up. That's the command I'd like to have.

Answer (score 1):

This information is *hidden* inside the `children` property of `DocumentSymbol` (returned by `vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider`):

```
let symbols = vscode.commands.executeCommand ('vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider');

console.log (symbols[0].children);
```

I write 'hidden' because `children` does not show, if you simply run `console.log (symbols);` in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API like that. Language support is self contained and usually does not provide its information to the outer world.

You would instead have to create your own parser, which processes the code to find symbol information.

Comment: But doesn't the vscode internal outliner use the LSP to provide the outline? (including sub-level outlining)

Comment: Maybe, depends on the provider, but I know no way to execute providers from your own code. They are registered with vscode and that knows how to trigger them.